# How to add a row in stimulsoft that show just in last page

Tags: stimulsoft

How to add a row in stimulsoft that show just in last page?

(I have a row that show sum of a column in every page and I want to have a row that sum of that column in whole report that show just in last page not every page of report)

Comment: Can you add to your question the code you're using?  What have you tried to make this work?

Comment: I can calculate sum of a column but when I assign it to footer band that row show in every page but I want to show that row in last page of report. How to do it?

Comment: {cSum(DataDataSource1,DataSource1.Hour)}

Answer (score 0):

use `ReporSummaryBand` and this will just show in last page of your report.

and use the following for sum of whole report:

```
{Sum(DataDataSource1,DataSource1.YourvalueVale)}
```